# How can I get access to a Highcharts chart through a DOM-Container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, highcharts

When I render a highcharts-chart to a div container, how can I get access to the chart object through the div-Container?

I don't want to make the chart variable global.

```
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: "testDivId",
                                ...
```

I want to access the chart outside of the context above like this (pseudocode), to call functions:

```
var chart = Highcharts.Chart("testDivId"); //access from id
chart.redraw();
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

### Highcharts 3.0.1

Users can use the highcharts plugin

```
var chart=$("#container").highcharts();
```

### Highcharts 2.3.4

Read from the [Highcharts.charts](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Highcharts.charts) array, for version 2.3.4 and later, the index of the chart can be found from the data on the `<div>`

```
 var index=$("#container").data('highchartsChart');
 var chart=Highcharts.charts[index];
```

### All versions

Track charts in a global object/map by container id

```
var window.charts={}; 
function foo(){
  new Highcharts.Chart({...},function(chart){  
      window.charts[chart.options.chart.renderTo] = chart;
  });
}

function bar(){
  var chart=window.charts["containerId"];
}
```

[Read Mode @ Highcharts Tips - Accessing Chart Object From a Container ID](http://ahumbleopinion.com/highcharts-tips-accessing-chart-object-from-container-id/)

### P.S.

Some additions were made in the newer versions of Highcharts since writing this answer and have been **taken from answers from [@davertron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049977/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-highcharts-chart-through-a-dom-container/13051825#comment19551539_13051825), [@Nerdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16007922/584676) and [@Frzy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368514/584676), please upvote their comments/answers as they deserve the credit** for these. Adding them here as this accepted answer would be incomplete without these

Comment: It looks like as of version 2.3.4 Highcharts does keep track of all of the charts on the page: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts

Comment: @davertron thanks for the update... thats a nice feature to have, don't think much code/effort was required to have this...

Comment: +1 for $("#container").data('highchartsChart') as the highcharts index.
it's very useful, thanks!

Comment: Any similar method I could use for highstock?

Answer (score 45):

you can do this

```
var chart = $("#testDivId").highcharts();
```

[check example on fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-setcategories/)

Comment: It didn't work for me, I had to use the @Frzy answer. I am using the version 4.1.4

Comment: not sure why it didn't work for you the fiddle example uses v4.2.3

Comment: It is returning the container element instead of the chart, and that is why @Frzy answer worked. Also, I found another solution: `$("#testDivId").highcharts({...}, function(chart) {...});`

Comment: it's definitely returning the object http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/86hLvc5s/ check the console output after you click the button

Comment: Yes, in the jsfiddle is doing that, I agree. But not for everybody is working the same, as you can see by the 11 upvotes of @Frzy answer

Answer (score 22):

```
var $chartCont = $('#container').highcharts({...}),
    chartObj = Highcharts.charts[$chartCont.data('highchartsChart')];
```

chartCont is jQuery Object.
chartObj is Highchart Chart Object.

This is using Highcharts 3.01

Answer (score 10):

Simply with pure JS :

```
var obj = document.getElementById('#container')
    Highcharts.charts[obj.getAttribute('data-highcharts-chart')];
```

Answer (score 9):

I found another way of doing it... mainly because I'm using Highcharts that are embedded in OutSystems Platform, and I don't have a way to control the way charts are created.

The way that I found was the following:

1. Give an identifying class to the chart using `className` attribute

   ```
   chart: {
       className: 'LifeCycleMasterChart'
   }
   ```
2. Define an auxiliary function to get the chart by class name

   ```
   function getChartReferenceByClassName(className) {
   var cssClassName = className;
   var foundChart = null;

   $(Highcharts.charts).each(function(i,chart){    
       if(chart.container.classList.contains(cssClassName)){
           foundChart = chart;
           return;
       }
   });

   return foundChart;
   ```

   }
3. Use the auxiliary function wherever you need it

   ```
   var detailChart = getChartReferenceByClassName('LifeCycleDetailChart');
   ```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 5):

Without jQuery (vanilla js):

```js
let chartDom = document.getElementById("testDivId");
let chart = Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.attr(chartDom, 'data-highcharts-chart')]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var chart1; // globally available
$(document).ready(function() {
      chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
         },
         xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
         },
         yAxis: {
            title: {
               text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
         },
         series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
         }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
         }]
      });
   });
```

The var chart1 is global so you can use to access de highchart object  doesnt matter wich is the container

```
chart1.redraw();
```

Answer (score 2):

... and with the help of a colleague... a better way to do it is...

```
getChartReferenceByClassName(className) {
    var foundChart = $('.' + className + '').eq(0).parent().highcharts();

    return foundChart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**@elo**'s answer is correct and upvoted, though I had to tidy it a little to make it clearer:

```
const myChartEl = document.getElementById('the-id-name');
const myChart = Highcharts.charts[myChartEl.getAttribute('data-highcharts-chart')];
```

`myChart` then becomes a live **Highcharts** object that exposes all current props present in the chart that's rendered in the `myChartEl`. Since `myChart` is a **Highcharts** object, one can chain prototype methods right after it, extend it or refer to it.

```
myChart.getTable();
myChart.downloadXLS();
setTimeout(() => Highcharts.fireEvent(myChart, "redraw"), 10);
```

One can also get `myChart` through `.highcharts()`, which is a `jQuery` plugin:

```
var myChart = $("#the-id-name").highcharts();
```

The *`jQuery` plugin* approach above requires `jQuery` to be loaded before the plugin is used, and of course the plugin itself. *It was the absence of this plugin that got me into looking for alternative ways to accomplish the same with pure vanilla JavaScript.*

**By using the pure JS approach I was able to do what I needed (the second code snippet) without having to rely on `jQuery`**: