# Highcharts: Setting charts options via html class

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When using `Highcharts.setOptions()` it's for all charts following after this function.

But I haven't found a way to do something like:

`$(".barcharts_overview").Highcharts.setOptions()` 
or `$(".asplinecharts_detailed").Highcharts.setOptions()` or like 
`$(".asplinecharts_detailed").setOptions()`

Is there a way to do something like this? My goal is, to define 2-3 option sets which should be used, when the div container has a class like "barcharts_overview" or "asplinecharts_detailed" to just define the settings once, while displaying multiple charts in different styles on one page.

Comment: The following question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253590/manage-multiple-highchart-charts-in-a-single-webpage/9607502#9607502

Comment: This also seems to be what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049977/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-highcharts-chart-through-a-dom-container

Comment: @djot thanks for editing, sorry forgot the code tags.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann
Seems i need a combination of both links. Thanks in advance, i'll reply/comment again, when finished testing.

And thanks to StackOverflow that i just can enter one user notification... :/

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you use setOptions, then options are added globally, but you can prepare switch/if which recognises which class exists (if one on page) and calls setOptions.