# Programmatically zoom out with highcharts-ng

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm working with Highcharts-ng https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Looking through the source code, I see there are some things going on in the directive with scope.$on that I can use to broadcast. For example...

```
scope.$on('highchartsng.reflow', function () {
  chart.reflow();
});
```

Then in my controller, I can call a watch function on a scope:

```
$scope.$watch("someElement", function(nV,oV){
  if(nV===oV) return;
  $scope.$broadcast('highchartsng.reflow');
});
```

This works fine and makes a lot of sense. What I don't understand is why I can't add additional things to the directive. For example, if I can call .reflow() from the directive, I should be able to call .zoomOut() just as easily, correct?

```
// This doesn't work when I add it to the directive..
scope.$on('zoomOut', function() {
  chart.zoomOut();
});

// And broadcast the change from a scope in the controller
$scope.$watch('someElement', function(nV,oV){
    if(nV===oV) return;
    $scope.$broadcast('zoomOut');
});
```

What can be done to make this work? And if it can't be done, how can I make jQuery control it instead? (Is it even possible to make jQuery take over certain aspects of the directive instead of relying on angular for everything?)

Comment: two things: 1. even though it's not the 'angular way' you can use DOM manipulation using angular.element (in a directive I believe you can just inject $element)
2. Check that you are broadcasting to the right scope. The easy way to check if that is the case is to broadcast to $rootScope instead of $scope and log something in the $on function to make sure you are receiving the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. As the comment above says make sure you are calling it on the right scope.

You could just use jquery to get a handle to the chart and then call whatever methods you want. See: [How can i get access to a Highcharts chart through a DOM-Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049977/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-highcharts-chart-through-a-dom-container)

I'm slow to add many of these types of events as they will apply to all charts on the page and don't seem a very angular way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks Pablojim and @ruedamanuel for your input. I thought I was going crazy. It turns out I just pointing to the highcharts-ng.min.js file and needed to switch it back to the one I was altering... One of these  days, I'll get my act together and not be such a noob. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Pablojim, hey, can you please look into my issue related to highcharts-ng
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513784/create-a-sticky-tooltip-in-highcharts-ng-implemented-in-jquery-highcharts