# Getting chart object when clicked on any bar of stacked bar chart(HighChart)

Tags: highcharts

I am working with Stacked Bar chart(High Chart),

I am trying to implement fallowing behaviour,

when clicked on any bar of stacked bar chart, want to highlight whole chart.
I am highlighting chart by changing background image(plotBackgroundImage) of chart, for this we need chart object. my question is how to get chart object when clicked on bar.

any suggestion regarding this is helpful.

Comment: The chart object is avaiable at all times. Combine it with point click. [How can i get access to a Highcharts chart through a DOM-Container](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13049977/2732991)

Comment: When using `plotOptions.series.point.events.click` handler you have access to `this.series.chart`. When using series click event handler, you have access to chart by `this.chart`.

Comment: And just in general, for this type of question - I find it very useful when trying to see what is returned in any javascript event to simply call console.log(this); and see what's there.

Comment: Thanks @pawel Fus,"this.series.chart" solved my problem.