# Set Scope in Angular-Charts.js after rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

Hi im currently trying to show multiple charts with angular-charts.js framework. My problem is that i need the same scale on each chart. At the moment each chart has its own scale based upon the data displayed. I can not predict the data before the charts are rendered. So I need something like a Callback function...

Is there any solution?

Using Angular 1.6.1

EDIT:

```
$scope.options = {
                  scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                            ticks: { min: 0, max: },
                              }]
                  }
                };
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumberOfSprints(numberOfSprints) track by $index">
                <h3>
                    Sprint {{$index+1}}
                </h3>
                <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                    <canvas class="chart-bar"
                      chart-data="GetData($index)"
                      chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-options="options">
                    </canvas> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

GetData calculates Data for each chart based on index

Comment: you tried services and factories ?? and create a single object of chart and create object aray and assign the same property of scale to each chart with angular.each

Comment: You should have better separate your architecture, between rendering and updating date. First, render your chart, then update with your data to chart. You can decide your trigger for updating data to chart.

Comment: Data for each chart is calculated by a function in a service. I can use a property for the scale but changes are not assumend by the chatrs

Comment: Add your code - other than that, the only advice we can give you is calculate your numbers first, and draw the charts afterwards.

Comment: I added the code for my problem

Comment: @Taree did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change a chart's option after it was render, you need to call the update function.

> .update(duration, lazy)
>
> Triggers an update of the chart. This can be safely called after
> replacing the entire data object. This will update all scales,
> legends, and then re-render the chart.

[Documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods)

#### Example:

```
// duration is the time for the animation of the redraw in milliseconds
// lazy is a boolean. if true, the animation can be interrupted by other animations
    
// Would update the first dataset's value of 'March' to be 50
myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 50; 
    
// Calling update now animates the position of March from 90 to 50.
myLineChart.update();
```

Comment: I tried this solution but for some reason Im not able to access my chart-element properly.
Is there a way to get not just the dom-element, but the Charts-Object?

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545742/getting-access-to-already-created-chart-js-chart/41575491#41575491

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution for my Problems.

I used a parent-controller to store my scale variable and in my Child Controllers a $watch expression to rerender each chart.

Parent:

```
$scope.max = 0;

    $scope.setMax = function(val){
        $scope.max = Math.max($scope.max, val);
        console.log($scope.max);
    }
```

Child:

```
$scope.$watch('max',function(){
    ...
});
```